# Smart Mailbox and Any Recipient rule not working

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, exchange

I've had a few smart mailboxes in Apple Mail which have worked fine so far, but I've noticed some odd behaviour lately (which may or may not have been there before).

Mailbox rules:

- Date received - is today
- Account - [my work mail account]
- Any recipient - contains [my work e-mail address]

[image: Mailbox definition]

The idea is to have a smart mailbox which shows all emails I received today (sent to me, not a mailing list of which I'm part of). The account is an Exchange mailbox.

This works without fault as long as I am the *single* recipient. As soon as the mail in question is addressed to multiple people (all in `To`), Apple Mail decides that it doesn't meet the mailbox criteria. I can't figure out why it decides to leave those messages out. Is there something I can check or can I define the criteria in a different way so it would work?

FYI: OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5 on a MacBook Pro (15", mid 2012).

Comment: Just a guess... any different with recipient **is** rather than contains?

Comment: @Tetsujin Same results actually.

Comment: ah, ok - was just an outside chance

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on my system. Unfortunately, I can't find a workaround.

Comment: I just realized that this is still an issue with Mail.app 9.3 on OS X 10.11.5 El Capitan. Since I wasn't able to find a workaround either, I decided to file a radar on https://bugreport.apple.com (issue #27437956).